# Move selected item to top and rest at bottom android java

Tags: java, android, collections

i have data in arraylist form[A,B,C,D] I want to change it to [B,A,C,D] means selected item to top and remaing item at bottom.Then if i select again let us assume C then it should be [C,B,A,D] The Problem is [A,B,C,D] again comes as i have to call each time [A,B,C,D]] arraylist in database means default arraylist[A,B,C,D] is called again .How can i acheive it? by creating index column in database or by what?

Comment: For example : A list

A B C D E

Given C , Switch to

C A B D E
i m able to do this like removing selected item position and add it to 0 index but 
I am getting [A,B,C,D,E] from db but i can not change order of [A,B,C,D,E] in db then what should i do in that case?how can i make changes in db so my [A,B,C,D,E] order do not change but another unique column values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by associating **Index** to ArrayList items in db. Whenever your list changes, update the db with changed items with index values.

Later when you again try to get data from db, use sort by index in db query.

Comment: i have created index column in db with 0,1,2,3.... default but i am fethching the data by [A,B,C,D]by where condition of some other column name so

Comment: so index will apply only that values but i want to apply index on all values

Comment: can u give an example how to do this

Comment: Add one extra column for index (not the default one). Now when the list items changes update those indices (Ex. initial list [A>0, B>1,C>2,D>3], updated list [B>0, A>1,C>2,D>3], then update A and B with new indices in db. Now when fetching from db create your query like "SELECT column-lists FROM table_name [ORDER BY index_column_name] [ASC. DESC]"

Comment: do i have to update c>2 and d>3 indexe values also in db?

Comment: and how to get selected and before selected elements index value in java?